# Error in Chrome only: XMLHttpRequest failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am running a WebApi and a WebClient application under IIS express (localhost) and receive this error only when I run them under Chrome.  It works fine under IE.

At this point I am attempting to just log in a user and I receive two error messages that I am not sure what they mean -

Failed to load resource: http://localhost:59822/api/accounts/login 
the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:59822/api/accounts/login. Invalid HTTP status code 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely happens due to the security settings in Chrome.

By default the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is rigorously enforced.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) is how to disable it in Chrome.